# How to add subfield to typescript interface child without repeating others?

Tags: typescript

We have an interface:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
  }
}
```

I want to define a child interface (with Foo as a parent), but with an addition of `d: string` field which is going to be nested in `b`

```
interface FooChild extends Foo {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
    d: string;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to define `FooChild` a shorter way: to skip mentioning `a` and `c` fields? E.g.:

```
interface FooChild extends Foo {
  // a: string; // this is OK
  b: {
    // c: string; // this meets a problem: Property c is missing...
    d: string;
  }
}
```

It is OK, if you have only one field `c` in `b`, but if you have 10 fields in `b`, and you have to repeat them all just to add one new field, it is too much code to repeat.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: There's no built in way to do this; you either need to use intersections, define new interfaces, or try to build a utility type that does a "deep intersection" for you.  All three are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgBy6W). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

my solution may have a little different approach than you expected. Firstly I've defined the child interfaces (`FooC`, `FooCD`), then parent (`Fooo`) which has generic type `T`, which will have type of one of the child interfaces. Then create the childs by extending the parent and providing generic type

```
interface FooC {
  c: string
}

interface FooCD {
  c: string
  d: string
}

interface Fooo<T> {
  a: string
  b: T
}

interface FooWithC extends Fooo<FooC> {}
const c: FooWithC = {
  a: "a",
  b: {
    c: 'c'
  }
}
interface FooWithCD extends Fooo<FooCD> {}
const cd: FooWithCD = {
  a: "a",
  b: {
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd'
  }
}
```